# how to change between 2 header xml files in navigation view?

Tags: java, android

I have two xml header files i want to show one of them before user login and the another header after login .

I am checking status of login  by shared preferences but i don't know  how to change the header xml file .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to remove the current header view ([removeHeaderView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html#removeHeaderView(android.view.View))) and inflate the new one and set it to the `NavigationView` ([inflateHeaderView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html#inflateHeaderView(int))) like this:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
// If the view has not been set in the xml then here should be a null check because there is going to be no header view 
// and there will be no need to remove that
View hView =  navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
navigationView.removeHeaderView(hView);
navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_my_other_header);
```

HIH

Comment: works perfect i change only last line of your solution as follwing
navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_my_other_header);

Thanks